# Parse Header in Post Call Python

Tags: python, web-services, rest

I am using rest client in my mozilla browser to call an auth service.
When i pass my credentials in Body, i get an **"auth-token"** . I then set this token in the header in the browser HEADERS tab.

I have to parse this header which i am setting  in the browser in my python script as a variable. Further, after getting this value in my script i have to authenticate the token for its validity.
However i am unable to get the tokens value in my script. My auth function is ready. I just have to fetch the token
How should i fetch this token value from the header ??

Code:

```
def check_authentication(auth):

  print "Auth" , auth

  chek_auth_url = ("http://10.168.2.161/auth/v/%s" % (auth)) 

  auth = requests.get(chek_auth_url)

  if auth.status_code == 200:

    return True
```

I have to pass the token as a paramter in this function and call in this   function in main for authentication.

```
  def crossdomain(origin=None, methods=None, headers=None, max_age=21600, attach_to_all=True, automatic_options=True):
if methods is not None:
    methods = ', '.join(sorted(x.upper() for x in methods))
if headers is not None and not isinstance(headers, basestring):
    headers = ', '.join(x.upper() for x in headers)
if not isinstance(origin, basestring):
    origin = ', '.join(origin)
if isinstance(max_age, timedelta):
    max_age = max_age.total_seconds()

def get_methods():
    if methods is not None:
        return methods

    options_resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
    return options_resp.headers['allow']

def decorator(f):
    def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if automatic_options and request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        else:
            resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
        if not attach_to_all and request.method != 'OPTIONS':
            return resp

        h = resp.headers
        h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
        h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = get_methods()
        h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(max_age)
        if headers is not None:
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
            #h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Content-Type"
        return resp

    f.provide_automatic_options = False
    return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
return decorator

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@crossdomain(origin='*', headers='Content-Type')
def get_storage():

  *check_authentication is called here and token is passed as a parameter*
  *if token is valid further task i hav to do*



if __name__ == '__main__':

  app.run(host='192.168.56.1', port=8080, threaded=True)
```

Comment: where is your script for retrieving token from browser ?

Comment: I am writing one. I have never worked with rest before so finding it difficult. I am a newbee in python

Comment: can someone suggest me a work around ??

Comment: Do you use any library for your Python server script? What is `auth` in your code? Who is calling `check_authentication`?

Comment: check_authentication will b called inside another method by a service. auth is just a parameter passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-Help is the best help..

Finally i found a fix:

The token value is fetched in the variable tokenValue. I can now do my further coding.

```
tokenValue = request.headers.get("token")

if tokenValue == None:
  return "x-auth-token not passed in header, please pass the token."
else:
  print "Token passed is", tokenValue
```